Rails & Postgres - schema dump conflict
I'm using Rails and Postgres. My database.yml looks like below
test:
  db_one:
    database: test_db
    migrations_paths: db/migrate
    schema_search_path: public
  db_two:
    database: test_db
    migrations_paths: db/db_two_migrate
    schema_search_path: custom_schema,public

The db_one connection points to the default public schema, and the db_two points to the custom_schema. They have separate migration paths.
To migrate the database, I'll need to do
rails db:migrate:db_one
rails db:migrate:db_two

This generates two schema files. The db_two_schema.rb contains all tables from the public schema and also its own tables.
The problem is both the db_one_schema.rb and db_two_schema.rb contain a create_schema "custom_schema" command. This results in an error when I try to load the db from the schema files. It says cannot create the custom_schema because it already exists.
I think the root cause might be the rails migration takes the database structure as a reference when running the migrations. It finds the new schema and then added the create_schema command in both schema files.
If my understanding is correct, is there a way to only include the create_schema command in one of the schema files?

Beware that the Ruby schema dumper is convenient but not always that good at preserving the schema. There comes a time when you need to switch to SQL dumps - not saying that's now but its something to keep in mind.
